# How to read the string into a file C++

Tags: c++

i have a little problem on writing the string into a file,
How can i write the string into the file and able to view it as ascii text?
because i am able to do that when i set the default value for str but not when i enter a str data
Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream out("G://Test.txt");

    if(!out) {
        cout << "Cannot open output file.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    char str[200];
    cout << "Enter Customers data seperate by tab\n";
    cin >> str;
    cin.ignore();
    out.write(str, strlen(str));
    out.seekp(0 ,ios::end);
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just as a sidenote. Having: char str[200]; and then reading text into it from the input is a bad idea. The moment someone types in more than 200 characters, your program will behave undefined and probably crash

Comment: `std::string` may not be well designed, but it's your friend.  `cin >> str` will work just fine if `str` is a `std::string`.

Answer (score 8):

Please use `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

std::string str;
std::getline(cin, str);
cout << str;
```

I'm not sure what the exact problem in your case was, but `>>` only reads up to the first separator (which is whitespace); `getline` will read the entire line.

Comment: Definately worth noting that << and >> with strings behave differently in relation to White Space. +1

Answer (score 1):

Just note that >> operator will read 1 word.

```
std::string   word;
std::cin >> word;  // reads one space seporated word.
                   // Ignores any initial space. Then read
                   // into 'word' all character upto (but not including)
                   // the first space character (the space is gone.

// Note. Space => White Space (' ', '\t', '\v'  etc...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're working at the wrong level of abstraction.  Also, there is no need to `seekp` to the end of the file before closing the file.

You want to read a string and write a string.  As Pavel Minaev has said, this is directly supported via `std::string` and `std::fstream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream out("G:\\Test.txt");

    if(!out) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open output file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Enter Customer's data seperated by tab\n";
    std::string buffer;
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
    out << buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to write C, use C.  Otherwise, take advantage of the language you're using.

Comment: I'd use `std::ofstream` fro writing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe no one found the problem. The problem was that you were using `strlen` on a string that wasn't terminated with a null character. `strlen` will keep iterating until it finds a zero-byte, and an incorrect string length might be returned (or the program might crash - it's Undefined Behavior, who knows?).

The answer is to zero-initialize your string:

```
char str[200] = {0};
```

Supplying your own string as the value of `str` works because those in-memory strings are null-terminated.